# Debugging SQL scripts best practices?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**The situation:**
When I try to make a function or stored-proc, I usually start with a plain query window with sql-code.  Often, I use @tblvar local tables to hold subsets of data needed later in the script.
During my testing of the developing script, I "select" the contents of the @tblvar-tables to observe the data to make sure it is correct for the scenario being tested.

Then, when I have debugged the complex query I then place that working code into a new stored-proc or user-defined-function.

But first, I need to "remove" or "comment-out" those "select @tblvar-tables" sentences.
I do this using the following sample/example code:

```
--DEBUG_SELECT 
SELECT '@tblvarCostsAll_1' AS 'QueryName', * FROM @tblvarCostsAll WHERE (UID_VEHICLE IN (1628,1638,1672)) ORDER BY DATE_RANGE_CODE, UID_VGROUP, UID_VEHICLE;
--DEBUG_RETURN RETURN;
```

It becomes simple for me to "search/find" the phrase "--DEBUG_" and adjust the commenting process by joining the separate --DEBUG_SELECT-line with the adjacent SELECT-line.

**The Question...**
Is there a best practice in how to develop good SQL code from queries to udf-functions and usp-stored-procs?

Thanks...John

Comment: SQL is far too flexible a language for there to be any kind of consensus on these types of things.  Do whatever works for you and arguably more importantly, everyone you have to work with as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks @iamdave.  Can you suggest an alternative scheme to developing udf-functions?

Comment: Not really no, as far as I am aware there is no such thing

Comment: For complex single queries, you can build a layer cake with CTEs: `WITH x AS (SELECT ...), y AS (SELECT ... FROM x)...` and each individual stage can be tested by leaving the CTEs alone and just by having `SELECT * FROM x` at the end (it works for `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` as well). This is not a full, general technique for debugging any T-SQL though (and such a thing would fall under "primarily opinion based").